# TF.Keras How to Fit a Model with TFRECORDS Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have written out a simple single TFRECORDS file that contains three features and a label.
As I am following tutorials, it seems that to use these TFRECORDS I need to create a dataset, parse the examples, do other things like normalization through map(). If this is not correct workflow I would be grateful to hear!

```
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("dataset.tfrecords")
    
    #parse the protobuffer
    
    def _parse_function(proto):
        # define your tfrecord again. 
        keys_to_features = {'weight_pounds': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
                            'gestation_weeks': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
                            'plurality': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
                            'isMale': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
                          
                           
                           }
        
        # Load one example
        parsed_features = tf.io.parse_example(proto, keys_to_features)
        
        # Turn your saved image string into an array
        #parsed_features['image'] = tf.decode_raw(
        #    parsed_features['image'], tf.uint8)
        
        return parsed_features
    
    hold_meanstd={
        'weight_pounds':[7.234738,1.330294],
        'gestation_weeks':[38.346464,4.153269],
        'plurality':[1.035285,0.196870]
    }
    
    def normalize(example):
        example['weight_pounds']=(example['weight_pounds']-hold_meanstd['weight_pounds'][0])/hold_meanstd['weight_pounds'][1]
        example['gestation_weeks']=(example['gestation_weeks']-hold_meanstd['gestation_weeks'][0])/hold_meanstd['gestation_weeks'][1]
        example['plurality']=(example['plurality']-hold_meanstd['plurality'][0])/hold_meanstd['plurality'][1]
        label=example.pop('isMale')
        return(example,label)

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(["dataset.tfrecords"]).map(_parse_function)
dataset =dataset.map(normalize)
dataset =dataset.batch(64)
```

Then once I have this dataset, I was thinking I could feed into a Keras model:

```
Dense = keras.layers.Dense
model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            Dense(500, activation="relu", kernel_initializer='uniform',
                  input_shape=(3,)),
            Dense(200, activation="relu"),
            Dense(100, activation="relu"),
            Dense(25, activation="relu"),
            Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
        ])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.01)

    # Compile Keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
    
model.fit(dataset)
```

This throws an error:

```
 ValueError: Layer sequential_1 expects 1 inputs, but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_1:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_2:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

The issue seems to be that the input dataset looks like three inputs instead of one? How to allow Keras to train on a TF RECORDS dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After specifying `input_shape=(3,)` in your first Dense layer, your keras model expects as an input a Tensor with the shape `(None,3)` (where `None` defines the batch size). We can take for example the following:

```
[
[0.0,0.0,0.0]
]
```

If we look a your `tf.data.Dataset`, we can see that it is returning a dictionary. Each input will look like:

```
{
"weight_pounds":[0.0],
"gestation_weeks":[0.0],
"plurality":[0.0]
}
```

which is a bit different from the `input_shape` specified above!

To fix that, you have two solution:

- drop the dictionary data structure. To do that, you can change your normalize function a bit:

```
def normalize(example):
    example['weight_pounds']=(example['weight_pounds']-hold_meanstd['weight_pounds'][0])/hold_meanstd['weight_pounds'][1]
    example['gestation_weeks']=(example['gestation_weeks']-hold_meanstd['gestation_weeks'][0])/hold_meanstd['gestation_weeks'][1]
    example['plurality']=(example['plurality']-hold_meanstd['plurality'][0])/hold_meanstd['plurality'][1]
    label=example.pop('isMale')
    # removing the dict struct
    data_input = [example['weight_pounds'], example['gestation_weeks'], example['plurality']]
    return(data_input,label)
```

- use a [layers.DenseFeatures](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/DenseFeatures?hl=en) as your input layer::

```
from keras.layers import Dense, DenseFeatures
from tensorflow.feature_column import numeric_column

feature_names = ['weight_pounds', 'gestation_weeks', 'plurality']
columns = [numeric_column(header) for header in feature_names]

model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            DenseFeatures(columns)
            Dense(500, activation="relu", kernel_initializer='uniform'),
            Dense(200, activation="relu"),
            Dense(100, activation="relu"),
            Dense(25, activation="relu"),
            Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
        ])
```